# insert div in article with just javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anyone help me with this, I want to be able to insert divs in an article that shows an Ad after certain `<p>` points.

i have it sort of working with using jquery but want a pure javascript way to do it if possible.

this is what i have at the moment

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvidSlot"></div><div>').insertAfter('#mvp-content-main p:nth-child(1) ');
      $('<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvid1Slot"></div><div>').insertAfter('.mvp-main-box p:nth-child(20) ');
      $('<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvid2Slot"></div><div>').insertAfter('.mvp-main-box p:nth-child(40) ');
      $('<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvid3Slot"></div><div>').insertAfter('.mvp-main-box p:nth-child(60) ');
      $( "<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvidSlot"></div><div>" ).insertAfter( "div.mvp-content-main p:eq(1)" );
});
```

**problem is:** it seems to ad one random div containing "advertisement" further down the page and doesn't show the actual advert there for some reason.  I'm thinking doing it with just javascript means i don't have to load jquery, getting rid of this "extra advertisement" and makes page load a bit faster:

Comment: You have a typo in your last line. Wrap the string with `'` instead of `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Pure JS solution):

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    document.querySelector('#mvp-content-main p:nth-child(1)').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvidSlot"></div><div>');
    document.querySelector('.mvp-main-box p:nth-child(20)').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvid1Slot"></div><div>');
    document.querySelector('.mvp-main-box p:nth-child(40) ').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvid2Slot"></div><div>');
    document.querySelector('.mvp-main-box p:nth-child(60) ').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvid3Slot"></div><div>');
    document.querySelector('div.mvp-content-main p:eq(1)').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<div class="ad-reporter-ahytrfg35423">Advertisement<div id="inreedvidSlot"></div><div>' );
})
```

Comment: great, that sort of works, as it puts the Ads in the article but it doesn't put them in order down the article. the order it puts them going down is 1Slot, 3Slot, Slot, 2Slot

Comment: another problem is that google consolue throws errors now     6 ms Slot /1001824/Golfwrx.com-HB/Golfwrx.com-HB-Vid-test does not have a container div with id: inreedvidSlot.
Warning 6 ms Slot /1001824/Golfwrx.com-HB/Golfwrx.comHB-Vid-test1 does not have a container div with id: inreedvid1Slot.
Warning 6 ms Slot /1001824/Golfwrx.com-HB/Golfwrx.comHB-Vid-test2 does not have a container div with id: inreedvid2Slot.
Warning 6 ms Slot /1001824/Golfwrx.com-HB/Golfwrx.comHB-Vid-test3 does not have a container div with id: inreedvid3Slot.